# How can I create a custom loading indicator in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Inside this page (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading-indicator#custom-indicators) says that I can create a custom loading indicator but not says how.

Somebody can help me - how to create and set this into to nuxt.config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a collection of default [loading indicators](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/packages/vue-app/template/views/loading) in Nuxt.js source code.

Basically, you can specify the HTML template to use as a `loadingIndicator` in `nuxt.config.js`.

```
export default {
  ..., // Other Nuxt configuration

  // Simple usage:
  loadingIndicator: '~/custom-locading-indicator.html',

  // Or with dynamic configuration variables passed via lodash template syntax
  loadingIndicator: {
    name: '~/custom-locading-indicator.html',
    color: '#000',
    background: '#fff'
  }
}
```

Note, that indicators can have access to

Comment: it's another loading.
I need for https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading-indicator
not for https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading

Comment: The info that I wanted is for: Custom Loading Indicator

Comment: How can I use an image as the loader in this html template? @aBiscuit

Comment: The same way you use in any HTML file - with an image tag (or background) and a link to the image. And place the image inside `static` folder.

Comment: in my nuxt.config.js 
 loadingIndicator: {
    name: '/loadingIndicator.html',
  },

and in static folder i have made on loadingIndicator.html file

but it didn't work. the loader is not visible.

but when i use collection of nuxt it work. custom didn't work.

Comment: As you can see in examples above, we use webpack alias for `name` property of `loadingIndicator`. This means, that path to html file is resolved during build process. At this point, I would not recommend putting indicator template file into a `static` static folder, as it served a different purpose. Instead, you can put it in `components` or a custom folder and provide a correct path. Example with `components` folder: `name: '~/components/loading-indicator.html'`. Also, suggest not to use camel case for html filenames.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need :

You can create a component for your app.
You can read about the [Nuxt Loading Here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading/)

- Set the component has `loading: <your-component-path>`
  Read more here [The loading indicator Property](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-loading-indicator/).
- For nuxt to load it on your pages, you need to add :

```
  loadingIndicator: {
    name: 'chasing-dots',
    color: 'purple',
    background: 'green'
  }
```

Here is an example of how I configured the component in my app.

```js
export default {

  // LoadingBar component
  loading: '~/path-to-your-loading-component/Loading.vue',
}
```

On the page you want to load, add this.

````js
export default {
  /*
   ** programmatically start the loader so we force the page to take x2seconds to load
   */
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
      setTimeout(() => this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(), 2000)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt also provides a `$loading` component so you can use it anywhere in your app, anyway you want to.
Using `$nuxt.$loading.get()` will return the current loading percentage.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Home page</h1>
    <div v-show="$nuxt.$loading.get() > 0">
      {{loadingIndicator}}%
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    loadingIndicator() {
      return this.$root.$loading.get()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I get an error: *`$nuxt.$loading.get is not a function`*

Answer (score 0):

following @femanso I managed to customise my loading component with `window.$nuxt.$root.$loading.percent` instead of `$nuxt.$loading.get()`

```
computed: {
    loadingIndicator() {
      return  window.$nuxt.$root.$loading.percent
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone stumbles into this and wants to get the current loading progress from a vue component, you can use this:

EDIT: It worked until I restarted the dev server, then it stopped working. So not sure if this is a viable solution.

```js
  computed: {
    nuxtLoading() {
      return this.$nuxt.$loading.percent
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap 5 spinner (https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/spinners/), mode: 'universal'

In
nuxt.config.js

loading: '~/components/loading.vue'

in components

```
<template>
  <div 
    v-if="isLoading"
    class="loader"
  >
    <div class="loader__spinner spinner-border text-primary" role="status">
      <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    start() {
      this.isLoading = true
    },
    finish() {
      this.isLoading = false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.loader {
  &__spinner {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
}
</style>
```

https://nuxtjs.org/guides/configuration-glossary/configuration-loading
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/custom-loading?from-embed=&file=/components/loading.vue