# How to add a page loader in Nuxt 3 application

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I’m building an application using Nuxt 3, I want to add a page loader until the website loads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53195180/15351296

Answer (score 13):

According to [this article](https://medium.com/@flanker72/nuxt3-complex-solutions-page-loading-indicator-e34b5a86be52). There are a simple but limited solution and a fully customized one.

### Built in  `<NuxtLoadingIndicator>`

`<NuxtLoadingIndicator>` includes a loading progress bar and can be used like this

```js
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtLoadingIndicator />
    <NuxtPage />
  <NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

But it has only one pre-defined UI and it can only customized with these few properties

- **Color:** The color of the loading bar.
- **Height:** Height of the loading bar, in pixels (default is 3).
- **Duration:** Duration of the loading bar, in milliseconds (default is 2000).
- **Throttle:** Throttle the appearing and hiding, in milliseconds (default is 200).

### Customizable Loader

If you need your custom loader like full-screen spinner with the backdrop, you need the different approach. This approach allows you to create any loader and show it when needed.

```js
<template>
  <div class="h-screen">
    <div v-if="loading" class="fixed left-0 top-0 h-0.5 w-full z-50 bg-green-500" />

    <NuxtLayout>
      <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
  const loading = ref(false);
  nuxtApp.hook("page:start", () => {
    loading.value = true;
  });
  nuxtApp.hook("page:finish", () => {
    loading.value = false;
  });
</script>
```

Nuxt3 provides application runtime hooks that have interceptors for `page:start` and `page:finish` events. To use them properly you need to use these hooks in this way (in the app.vue or your custom component):

Comment: I think setting `true` as initial value to `loading` variable is more logical solution 

Comment: @selim yeah he probably going to set it to true initially. It's just an example he's use case may require adding changes

Answer (score 3):

"The `<NuxtLoadingIndicator>` component displays a progress bar on page navigation." – from the Nuxt3 Documentation for [`<NuxtLoadingIndicator>`](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/components/nuxt-loading-indicator/).

I think that is what's used to display the loading indicator in dev setup as well.

Comment: Looking through the source code for `NuxtLoadingIndicator` it doesn't actually show the current loading progress of the page and is simply just a bar that will grow over a given time. It's a quick and easy solution but doesn't give any meaningful information to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a custom solution for Nuxt3, using `pinia` for state management and global middleware and this solution works the same as [Nextjs-ProgressBar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-progressbar)

`stores/ui.js`

```
import { defineStore, acceptHMRUpdate } from "pinia";

const useUiStore = defineStore("uiStore", {
    state: () => {
        return {
            pageLoader: false,
        };
    },
    actions: {
        setPageLoader(value) {
            this.pageLoader = value

        },
    },
});

if (import.meta.hot) {
    import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useUiStore, import.meta.hot));
}

export default useUiStore;
```

`middleware/ui.global.js`

```
import useUiStore from "~~/stores/ui";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async(to, from) => {
    useUiStore().setPageLoader(true)
})
```

`components/LoaderIndicator.vue`

```
<script setup>
import useUiStore from '~~/stores/ui';

const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();

nuxtApp.hook("page:finish", () => {
    if(useUiStore().$state.pageLoader == true){
        useUiStore().setPageLoader(false)
    }
});

</script>
<script>
export default {
    watch: {
    showLoader(newVal, oldVal) {
      if (newVal == true) {
        this.$refs.progressBar.style.opacity = '1';
        this.$refs.progressBar.style.transitionDuration = '1000ms';
        this.$refs.progressBar.style.width = '40%';
      } else if (newVal == false) {
        this.$refs.progressBar.style.transitionDuration = '1000ms';
        this.$refs.progressBar.style.width = '100%';
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.$refs.progressBar.style.opacity = '0';
          this.$refs.progressBar.style.transitionDuration = '0ms';
          this.$refs.progressBar.style.width = '0%';
        }, 1000);
      }
    },
  },
  computed: {
    showLoader() {
      return useUiStore().$state.pageLoader;
    }
  },
};
</script>
<template>
    <div ref="progressBar" class="fixed left-0 top-0 z-50 transition-all bg-orange h-[3px] LoadingBar shadow-[0_0_10px] shadow-orange " :style="{ width :'0%' }"></div>
</template>
```

`app.vue`

```
<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
        <LoaderIndicator />
        <NuxtPage />
    </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

Please comment for optimizations, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<NuxtLoadingIndicator>` I've used global middleware + `page:finish` hook like:

```js
<template>
    <div v-show="show">
        Loading...
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
    const show = ref(false);

    addRouteMiddleware('global-loader', () => show.value = true, { global: true })
    nuxtApp.hook('page:finish', () => show.value = false)
</script>
```

So on every route change, we show the loader and hide it when the page is displayed.

You can replace template with the one you want, some spinner or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think this also helpful but it involves javascript.

```html
<div id="loading">Loading...</div>
```

`~/plugins/loading.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.hook('page:finish', () => {
        const loadingElement = document.querySelector('#loading')
        if (loadingElement) {
            loadingElement.remove()
        }
    })
})
```

Once the hook triggers, it will remove the spinner in the document.