# Is it possible to replace Nuxt 3 default page loading animation?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

**Answered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76771545/nuxt-3-where-to-customize-spa-loading-svg/76771704#76771704), thanks [@ReaganM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21341655/reaganm)!**

We are currently building a Nuxt 3 / Vue 3 / TypeScript web app. We would like to replace the [Default Nuxt Loading Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKZ2j.png) on page load/refresh (the animated Nuxt logo).
We have defined a custom loading indicator component.

**Desired behavior**

The loading indicator on page load or refresh should look like this: [Custom Loading Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW7xG.png). The component is animated, but that is secondary.

**What we have tried so far**

- Added the `<NuxtLoadingIndicator />` as descriped in the [Docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-loading-indicator), but that does not show up on page load.
- Tried to customize the loading indicator by adding the following lines of code to `nuxt.config.ts` as described in the [Docs](https://stackoverflow.com), although it is Nuxt 2 and both options did not work. 
  *Option a) (not the preferred way, but just to test if it does have an effect)*

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'],
    ssr: false,
    //@ts-ignore
    loadingIndicator: {
    name: 'chasing-dots',
    color: '#604081',
    background: '#ffffff'
  }
  // more configs...
})
```

*Option b)*

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'],
    ssr: false,
    //@ts-ignore
    loading: '~/components/general/LoadingIndicator.vue',
    // more configs...
})
```

- Tried to use the application hooks `page: start` and `page: finish` as described in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74161609/how-to-add-a-page-loader-in-nuxt-3-application) – no success.

Here is what the `LoadingIndicatore.vue` component looks like:

```
<template>
    <div 
        v-if="loading"
        id="loadingIndicator" 
        ref="loadingIndicator" 
        class="loadingIndicator text-center" 
        :style="'margin-top: ' + this.computedYposition + 'px; margin-left: ' + this.computedXposition + 'px'"
    >
        <div class="loadingIndicatorAnimation">
            <img src="~/assets/images/Loader.svg" width="104" height="70">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center loadingText">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            windowHeight: document.documentElement.clientHeight,
            computedXposition: 0,
            computedYposition: 0,
            loading: false
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.getWindowDimensions);
        this.centerLoadingIndicator();
    },
    unmounted() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.getWindowDimensions);
    },
    methods: {
        getWindowDimensions() {
            this.windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            this.centerLoadingIndicator();
        },
        centerLoadingIndicator() {
            this.computedYposition = '-' + ((this.$refs.loadingIndicator.clientHeight / 2));
            this.computedXposition = '-' + ((this.$refs.loadingIndicator.clientWidth / 2));
        },
        start() {
        this.loading = true
      },
      finish() {
        this.loading = false
      }
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.loadingIndicator
{
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.loadingIndicatorAnimation
{
    -webkit-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite;
    animation: pulse 2s linear infinite;
    opacity: 0.1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse 
{
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes pulse 
{
  50% { opacity: 1; }
}

.loadingText
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #999;
}
</style>
```

Can anyone help us with this issue? 
(I am quite new to Nuxt/Vue, please have mercy :) )

Comment: Your question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76771704/21341655. Hope that helps you

Comment: @ReaganM it works like a charm, thank you so much!!! I would love to upvote your answer, but I am too new to this community to do so :(
I hope it enlightens your heart to know that you have made my day (or my whole week!) by answering my question :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad I could be of help 